# tkinter grid method won't work

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have this code, and the label that i make is not appearing where i want it, it just appears in the 0,0 position please fix Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.sumbit_lbl = Label(self, text = "Does this work?")
        self.sumbit_lbl.grid(row = 2, column = 3)



root = Tk()
root.title("Does this work?")
root.geometry("200x200")

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you expecting to see in the rows 0 and 1, and the columns 0, 1 and 2? You've put nothing in them, so they have a width and height of zero.

In other words, it's working as expected. For a row or column to be visible, it needs either a minsize specified, or something in the row or column. There's a few other ways to make it visible, but it all boils down to you having to explicitly arrange for empty rows or columns to be visible.

If you want to prove to yourself that your widget actually is in the row and column you specified, you can give all of your empty rows and columns a minimum size. For example, add this in your constructor:

```
for row in range(4):
    self.grid_rowconfigure(row, minsize=8)
    for col in range(4):
        self.grid_columnconfigure(col, minsize=8)
```

Comment: i dont understand i used the grid method to PLACE the button at that position

Comment: @user2525477: your widget _is_ at row 2, column 3. The problem is, row 0 and row 1 have zero height so they are invisible. Also, columns 0, 1 and 2 have zero width, so they are invisible too.